# Comparing a DateTime attribute to DateTime.now gives unexpected result

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm facing an issue with comparing an Active Record DateTime attribute value to the DateTime.now.
The result I'm expecting and getting is different.

I needed the result of

```
time_now = DateTime.now #Thu, 23 Jul 2020 13:03:26 +0530
@movies = Movie.where('show_time > ?', time_now)
```

The above code expected to give the result: Movies which starts after `Thu, 23 Jul 2020 13:03:26 +0530`

But actually gives Movies starts from another time (day from the beginning).

When i checked my log the query given to db was

```
SELECT  "movies".* FROM "movies" WHERE (show_time > '2020-07-23 07:42:49.391379') ORDER BY "movies"."start_time" ASC LIMIT $11
```

The time here is `2020-07-23 07:42:49.391379`

I don't understand why this happen is there any way avoid this.

Answer (score 0):

Your `DateTime.now` is in a timezone with +5:30, that's why you can see this value `#Thu, 23 Jul 2020 13:03:26 +0530`.

Now when calling ActiveRecord, it will take the GMT value and checks for it. Your `starts_at` in the database should also be in `GMT` for daylight saving and anything else related to times and dates.

I would suggest that you fix the dates you have in your database ( always have them in GMT ) and that way your query should work.

Example: If a movie starts at `13:30 + 5:30`, it should be saved as `08:30 + 00:00` in your database.